# How to flatten a nested parquet using java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

How to flatten a nested parquet using java spark

[image]

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

I want to flatten this using spark java for saving as parquet/csv for inserting to Redshift

[image]

Comment: Can you mention the expected sample output?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/za.co.absa.hermes/utils_2.11/0.2.0 / has a `HelperFunctions. flattenDataFrame` method